# Could we use WinApp Driver to automate a couple of manual task instead of testing

Tags: selenium, automation, winappdriver

The current place that I work at manually builds the QA websites in a set of convoluted steps. Those steps range from getting on a remote windows desktop, downloading the codebase of the new website and database on the remote desktop, then pasting them in different windows desktop apps (Everything is happening on a remote windows desktop). All of these steps are quite manual but since there are many QA
websites of the company, it takes a lot of time for the person tasked with doing this. So, I was hoping to automate this task and found about WinApp Driver. On using with selenium, it will be able to get the work of automating the builds done but I'm unsure of going down that route since selenium is mostly used for testing and not automating.

Can someone attest if doing automations with WinApp Driver + selenium is a good practice (and sustainable in the long-run) and if not, then can you suggest me with something that is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as long as you have access to those desktop app's source code it's possible.  But there's probably a better way to automate these tasks.  (Some sort of database to database transfer maybe...)